# Save file to server application directory in Jersey API

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jersey

I am using the Jersey API to consume the multipart data(photo) and I like to save it server application directory instead of any other drive. I saved successfully in any other drive like D drive but can not find the way to save it in server application directory.

```
@POST
@Path("uploadphoto")
@Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
@Produces("text/plain")
public String uploadNotices(@FormDataParam("file") InputStream uploadedInputStream) {
    String uploadedFileLocation = "d:/1.jpg";
    // save it
    try {
        writeToFile(uploadedInputStream, uploadedFileLocation);
    } catch(Exception e) {
        return "no";
    }
    return "yes";
}

// save uploaded file to new location
private void writeToFile(InputStream uploadedInputStream, String uploadedFileLocation) throws Exception {
    OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(new File(uploadedFileLocation));
    int read = 0;
    byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];

    out = new FileOutputStream(new File(uploadedFileLocation));
    while ((read = uploadedInputStream.read(bytes)) != -1) {
        out.write(bytes, 0, read);
    }
    out.flush();
    out.close();
}
```

Comment: You shouldn't save files in the deployed application in the first place. Why do you want to do that? This might be a huge security leak...

Comment: I like to save it in the NEWFOLDER of the application directory. How can i save it. Please help me to do this

Comment: Do not do that! Somebody can upload a jsp to that folder and will be able to take over the server in 1 minute.

Comment: So Please suggest where to save it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its solve my problem

```
@Context
private ServletContext context;

String filePath = context.getRealPath("images/");   
File file = new File(filePath);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your jersey web application runs within a JVM on the Server such as Tomcat. The root file path of your application is typically the folder of your Tomcat Server. To get this folder path you can easily do the following:

```
String sRootPath = new File("").getAbsolutePath();
```

You can either use the root folder or any other custom folders created by you. Try this, hope it works.

Comment: I like to create the folder on server programmatically. So I need the location of the application directory where my application in the server location. SO how can i that location?

Comment: I like to get this path "E:\EclipseJ2ee\workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\Home Bulletin" run time. This is location where my application is deployed. So how can i get this path?

Comment: It giving my eclipse directory not the application workspace where application deployed. Its giving "D:\eclipse"

Comment: @Android is it a pluign project?

Comment: No I created own Dynamic Project.

Comment: @Android Then why it is saved in plugins folder?

Answer (score 0):

You should save these files in `System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir")` for example, which is a designated are for temporary files.

Comment: I like to save the files in permanent folder not the temporary.

Comment: Then select any folder, which is not the application folder and has sufficient space. Storing uploaded files permanently in a folder on the application server doesn't sound like a good plan by the way. You should store them in some sort of repository (CMS or DB or at least a shared drive).

Comment: If I like to save it on application directory please tell me what is the way to do so. Its my requirement to save it in application folder.

Comment: Check the other answer, where `File("")` is the folder of your application server's binary probably, that should technically work.

Comment: It giving my eclipse directory not the application workspace where application deployed. Its giving "D:\eclipse"

Comment: Well that is the path of the binary if you are using eclipse... you could try the following: `getClass().getClassLoader().getResource(fileName).getFile()` where `fileName` should be something that is on your webapps classpath.

Comment: I did not get you proper. Please elaborate it little bit more. "fileName should be something that is on your webapps classpath."